# Find latitude of point on great circle given longitude

Tags: wgs84, great-circle

I am trying to find out wether my implementation has faults and/or if there is a better method.

---

**The problem:**

Given two points (Lat/Long) defined over the WGS84 ellipsoid, find the point lying on the great circle that connect them and has a given Longitude

---

**My approach:**

- Convert the two points to ECEF coordinates
- Derive the orientation of the plane where the great circle lies (cross product of the two ECEF vectors)
- Derive the orientation of the meridian plane containing the point we are looking for (we know the longitude and that is perpendicular to the equator, so we only need sin/cos of the longitude)
- Derive the ECEF vector of the sought point (is the intersection of the two planes, we need only the cross product of the two plane orientations)
- Find the latitude of the point (is the arcsin of the third vector component, when normalized)

---

**My doubts:**

- When converting to ECEF I was using the fact that the local earth radius is not constant, and thus I was computing it to correctly weight the three components. When I tried to plot my computed points vs the great circle on online maps (googlemaps, skyvector) they seemed a little bit off and I solved the discrepancy by removing the weighting (i.e., ECEF on a perfect sphere). Who is right?
- Is there a better way? (that maybe avoids mapping to ECEF?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the wikipedia page on [great-circle navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_navigation).  Following the prescription there, you compute the heading of the great circle at the first point.  Then you can compute the intersection of the resulting path with a particular meridian.  (This addresses the problem on a sphere.  The ellipsoidal problem is a little more involved.  A good place to start is [geodesics on an ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid).)